# Midnight Commander: sftp connection using aliases from ssh config

Tags: ssh, sftp, mc, ssh-config

## Problem description

I try to connect to remote server in one of two panels of **Midnight Commander** using **SFTP link...** submenu. Unfortunately, mc does not pass my `~/.ssh/config` file to `sftp`. Therefore typing `sftp://myhostalias` results in error message

> Cannot chdir to "/sftp://myhostalias"

Here is a content of `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host myhostalias
    HostName server.url.domain
    User myusername
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa-myhostalias
```

### Please, note the following:

- `sftp://myusername@server.url.domain` works fine followed by inputting my password. I guess, this should not work if password authentication is disabled.
- `sftp myhostalias` from terminal also works fine.

## Question

What way should I connect to the remote server from mc **SFTP link...** menu using the aliases from my current ssh config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One should use **Shell link...** submenu instead of **SFTP link...** one. Type something like this in the address field: `sh://myhostalias/~` or simply `myhostalias` (see `ssh_config` example above).

Concerning **SFTP link...**, I didn't manage to use it that way from mc gui. Anyway, using aliases with `sftp` in CLI is straightforward.